# Task.Delay vs DispatcherTimer?

Tags: c#, task, async-await, delay, dispatchertimer

I'm considering use `Task.Delay()` for a non-stop timer, because it's more simple and readable.

As I'm new to .NET, I see no significant difference between the two codes. Can you show me the difference (if there is any) between them?

```
// Create variable at some place
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
timer.Tick += timer_Elapsed;
timer.Start();

// Function other place
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff
    }
```

vs

```
// Every thing inside a function
async void TaskTimer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you start TaskTimer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two major differences:

1. The `Task.Delay` approach will delay the specified amount of time *between* cycles, while the `DispatcherTimer` approach will start a new cycle on the specified cycle time.
2. `Task.Delay` is more portable, since it does not depend on a type tied to a specific UI.

Comment: I don't care very much about time. I only care it can repeate and perfomance. As far as I know, both create background threads add rise an event callback at the time approach. Do they are same perfomance?

Comment: Performance is comparable. Neither of them create background threads.

Comment: @StephenCleary: is it correct to use ConfigureAwait(false) unless we want to do stuff on the UI thread?

Comment: @Dunken: Yes, you should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for every `await` in a method that doesn't require a specific context (such as a UI context).